# Use config PHP document in JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a PHP config document with these line

**config.php:**

```
define("BASE_URL","http://192.168.1.1");
```

But I'm need these in JS/JQuery. How can i do this?

Maybe I will have to create a JS config file too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the top of your document, you can use :

```
<script>
    var baseUrl = "<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>";
</script>
```

Then you can use `baseUrl` variable in your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

You should require the config file first, Echo the PHP value.

```
<?php
 require_once('pathToconfig/config.php')
?>

 <script>
   let baseUrl = "<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>";
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the baseurl variable in your html files, you can then use it for other loading your js scripts and ajax request. Like so:

```
<script>
    var base_url = "<?php echo BASE_URL;?>";
</script>

//load css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>css/bootstrap.min.css">

//load jquery 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>

//use js variable base_url for ajax request too
 $.ajax({
      url:base_url+"your-url-here",
      type: "POST",
      data: params,
      dataType: "json"
  })
  .done(function(res){
      //do something here

  })
  .fail(function(xhr, textStatus){
      console.log("Got error.");
      return;
 })
```